# Host 3rd party executables on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I got a batch file which relies on some binaries, namely:

- 7za.exe (7zip command line version)
- find.exe (which requires cygwin1.dll)
- ResourcesExtract.exe ( http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/resources_extract.html )

I want to put that batch script on github for further development. What is the most elegant way to deal with those binaries?

- store them in main repo? definitely not
- store them in other repo and use as submodule?
- put them in 'Releases'? I don't think that's what 'Releases' are meant for.
- put them in README as requirement?
- ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add them as requirements in the README and provide instructions on how to install them, and/or provide a script to install them.